# ¿Cómo elaborar una anidada con 3 condiciones sin parar el curso?

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy empezando con el idioma y tengo este problema. El código es este:

```
if (x){
    if (y1){
        if (z1){
        }else if (z2){
   }else if (y2){
         if (z1){
        }else if (z2){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando introduzco un valor correspondiente a ( x) y luego otro que se encuentra en el parámetro de (y2), se detiene la ejecución y no continúa el programa.

Supongo que el problema se debe a la introducción de las variables de terceras (z1 y z2) dependientes de y1, pero no sé cómo escribirlo de forma correcta.

Así que, me gustaría saber la forma de evitarlo la pausa del programa y obtener el resultado, manteniendo el contenido original.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más específico y detallar mejor el resultado que quieres obtener?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Los condicionales que contienen un else if deben contener una condicion final "else" que hace que en cualquier otro caso diferente a los anteriores, haga lo que está dentro de esas llaves. Si no la pones así sea vacía, los condicionales tendrán problemas.